# How can I parse this xml using powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, xml-parsing

i need some regex help to parse out powershell objects from log file.

Looking to make a powershell object with these note properties:

```
ACVS_D = Date
ACVS_TI = Info
ACVS_C = Name
ACVS_M = Message
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you!

Example of xml in .log file:

```
<ACVS_T>
    <ACVS_D>12/23/2016 03:25:14.324</ACVS_D>
    <ACVS_TI>db818c30-cdb9-4482-9b51-8f6aad8e914c,C?Cure Reports Server Component,svc-ccureMAS</ACVS_TI>
    <ACVS_C>CrossFireWindowsService</ACVS_C>
    <ACVS_S>SoftwareHouse.CrossFire.Server.Shared.CrossFireWindowsService.TraceMessage( String methodName, String message )
</ACVS_S>
    <ACVS_M>
        CrossFireReportServer.ReconnectToServer() connected at 12/23/2016 3:25:14 AM
    </ACVS_M>
<ACVS_ST>

    </ACVS_ST>
</ACVS_T>
<ACVS_T>
    <ACVS_D>12/23/2016 03:25:14.324</ACVS_D>
    <ACVS_TI>6af6dfab-c890-42c5-acd2-a9520e9742da,C?Cure Reports Server Component,svc-ccureMAS</ACVS_TI>
    <ACVS_C>CrossFireWindowsService</ACVS_C>
    <ACVS_S>SoftwareHouse.CrossFire.Server.Shared.CrossFireWindowsService.TraceMessage( String methodName, String message )
</ACVS_S>
    <ACVS_M>
        CrossFireReportServer.ReconnectToServer() connected at 12/23/2016 3:25:14 AM
    </ACVS_M>
<ACVS_ST>

    </ACVS_ST>
</ACVS_T>
```

Comment: Don't do it with regexes.

Comment: `Select-Xml -Path Log.xml -XPath 'RootNodeHere/ACVS_T' | ForEach { $_.Node ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest using regex unless it is a **very big** file.
You need a regex search string like this `(?<=<ACVS_T>)((.|\n)*)(?=<\/ACVS_T>)`
please adjust for each part you need.

You can just add a root node and interpret this as a XML file.
As the example below:

```
$File = "PathToFile"

$XML =  [XML]("<Root>" + (Get-Content -Path $File) + "</Root>" )

$XML.Root.ACVS_T | ForEach-Object {
    $Obj = '' | Select-Object -Property ACVS_D, ACVS_TI, ACVS_C, ACVS_S, ACVS_M, ACVS_ST
   $Obj.ACVS_D = $_.ACVS_D
   $Obj.ACVS_ST = $_.ACVS_ST
   $Obj.ACVS_C = $_.ACVS_C
   $Obj.ACVS_S = $_.ACVS_S
   $Obj.ACVS_M = $_.ACVS_M
   $Obj.ACVS_ST = $_.ACVS_ST
   $Obj
}
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped!

Comment: Could you please accept this as te answer?